# Error object doesnt support named arguments VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I just tried to code VBA today, here's what I got myself into:

*the SQLConnection module*

```
Function connectDB(ByVal sqldbname As String) As ADODB.Connection
Dim objMyConn As ADODB.Connection
Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
Select Case sqldbname
    Case Is = "MYDB"
        objMyConn.ConectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=db_name;User ID=dbadmin;Password=dbpwd;"
End Select
objMyConn.Open 
End Function
```

*the Sheet1 objects*

```
Sub main()
'MsgBox "WELCOME DUCK!"
Dim objMyConn As ADODB.Connection
Set objMyConn = SQLConnection.connectDB("MYDB") 
End Sub
```

I always get "object doesn't support named arguments" error msg.

--After put in Option Explicit (Sub main not defined)

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
'MsgBox "WELCOME DUCK!"
Dim objMyConn As ADODB.Connection
Set objMyConn = SQLConnection.connectDB("MYDB")
Set objMyRecordset = SQLConnection.getdata(objMyConn, "SELECT * FROM MYTBL")
End Sub
```

--*the getdata function*

```
Function getdata(ByVal objMyConn As ADODB.Connection, ByVal strSQL As String) As ADODB.Recordset
Dim objMyRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
objMyRecordset.Open strSQL
Set getdata = objMyRecordset
End Function
```

Comment: at a minimum, objMyConn  would have to be public/global and your function should be a helper sub with parameters byRef.

Comment: use **Option Explicit** (vbe, tools, options, require variable declaration)

Comment: There is a small typo in `ConectionString` (should be `ConnectionString`). Where do yo get the error?

Comment: And your function is not setting a return value, i.e. you are missing `Set connectDB = objMyConn` at the end of the function.  (At the moment, `Set objMyConn = SQLConnection.connectDB("MYDB")` is setting `objMyConn` in `main` to `Nothing`.)

Comment: `connectDB` should also return the `objMyConn` object. Add a `Set connectDB = objMyConn` line before the `End  Function` line.

Comment: @Vincent G thanks, the typo is the perpetrator for this error. i'm afraid i didnt understand the reason for the syntax that you point out `Set connectDB = objMyConn`. why i have to assign the ADODB connection to the class itself ?

Comment: @Jeeped is there reason why ByVal cant be used in the function? and whats a helper sub? and whats option explicit? i apologize for my lack of knowledge, i'm still new to VBA but i code java before this.

Comment: @user2300035 - hmmm ... this would be easier to explain in C/C++ but I'll try. byRef passes over a pointer to the same memory address so if you make changes it is instantly reflected in the original. byVal passes over a copy of the original so any changes are only retained by the copy, not the original. In short, byRef has quantum entanglement; byVal does not. For your other questions, get your google out.

Comment: @Vincent G i meant the **Function** not the class* obviously no class involved here. sorry

Comment: @Jeeped so a helper is like utility sub that can be called by other part of code. i believe thats what im doing. option explicit restrict usage of undeclared variable..why would anyone use undeclared variable. i think that it is irresponsible to not declare any variable. but why would i need to use option explicit for my function?

Comment: @YowE3K sure it does. `Set objMyConn = SQLConnection.connectDB("MYDB")` i assign it to any value returned from connectDB function. am i not doing it right?

Comment: @user2300035 because if you misspell a var, method, property or function while writing code, option explicit will instantly find it rather than vba's lazy compiler creating somethig.

Comment: @Jeeped ahh i see. so this is for best practice.  i will use it in all my code after this. and that is why..maybe how the typo is not highlighted by the error msg Thanks :)

Comment: No, you are not doing it right.  You are missing `Set connectDB = objMyConn` at the end of the function so that the function has a return value.  At the moment, your line in `main` which says `Set objMyConn = SQLConnection.connectDB("MYDB")` is setting `objMyConn` (the variable that is defined as local to `main`) to be `Nothing` because you have never set `connectDB` to be anything.

Comment: @YowE3K if i get it right, the way vba returns result from function is by assigning the result back to the function inside the function. so in a sense the function itself behave as a variable. is that correct?

Comment: @Jeeped i add the `option explicit` thing on the Sheet1 code and my `sub main()` apparently is not defined.  can you help me on this?

Comment: Yes, to return a result from your function you would write `Set connectDB = objMyConn`.